# Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments in .../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php on line 133

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, sales-order, history

I am testing CE ver 1.9.1.1 and discover the error. To replicate, go to any sales order page in admin and enter "80%" in the comment history, click the button *Submit Comment*. So far so good, then hit F5 to refresh the page and you'll see the error:

> Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments  in .../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php on line 133

Here's the function that contains line 133:

```
public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    if (is_string($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $links = array();
        $i = 1;
        $regexp = '@(<a[^>]*>(?:[^<]|<[^/]|</[^a]|</a[^>])*</a>)@';
        while (preg_match($regexp, $data, $matches)) {
            $links[] = $matches[1];
            $data = str_replace($matches[1], '%' . $i . '$s', $data);
            ++$i;
        }
        $data = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
        return vsprintf($data, $links);
    }
    return Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
}
```

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: This has been reported [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/519)

Comment: Also [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/697) and will be fixed in the upcoming CE 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percent sign used for conversion specification in **vsprintf**. So, you just need to escape it.

update

```
if (is_string($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
```

to

```
if (is_string($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $data = str_replace('%', '%%', $data);
```